# Proving Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-verification, rolles-theorem

Trying to prove Rolle's Theorem, which says that for a function $f$ continuous over $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$ (no idea why the endpoints aren't included here), such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists a point $c$ where $a \lt c \lt b$ and $f'(c) = 0$.

It makes sense to me intuitively but I am not actually sure how you prove it.

If $f$ is a constant function $f(x) = k$ then at least I can show that $f(a) = f(c) = f(b) = k$, and $f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{k - k}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0$.

But if $f$ is not a constant function I'm at a loss because there are infinitely many types of functions that could be connecting the points at $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$. I don't know how to prove that there must be at least one maximum or minimum present in between.

But let's suppose we know such a maximum exists at $x=c$. This means $f(c+h) \leq f(c)$ for all $h$. Then:

$$f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} \geq 0$$

$$f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} \leq 0$$

(Do I need to prove these two statements more explicitly? The numerator is always $\leq 0$ and the direction of the inequality depends on whether $h>0$ or $h<0$)

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(c)$ is defined and equal to the two-sided limit, so

$$f'(c) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} = 0$$

I mean is this enough to prove it?

Comment: "no idea why the endpoints aren't included here": basically, the function can have a step discontinuity at a (or b or both), so it's not differentiable *at* a (or b or both) but the theorem is still true.

Comment: @Nick If $a$ and $b$ are step discontinuities then doesn't that violate the continuity condition over $[a,b]$?

Comment: @user525966: function can be continuous but not differentialble at a point, i.e. $|x| \:at \: x=0$

Comment: @Vasya Right but if the endpoints are jump discontinuities doesn't that make the function discontinuous?

Comment: No: it's continuous on the closed interval, but for $x < a$ say, we are stepping out of the closed interval: the function may be discontinuout at every such point, non-differentiable at every such point. The point is it's continuous in the closed interval and differentiable in the open interval except possibly at the end points. In any case, this is a minor point.

Comment: @user525966: see my example for absolute value function

Comment: @Nick Oh a jump from $x<a$ to $x=a$, that makes sense then. I assumed you had meant a jump from $x=a$ to $x>a$

Comment: The left hand limit is less than or equal to 0, and the right-hand limit is greater than or equal to 0. And the it if is differentiable, the left hand limit equals the right hand limit.  Therefore the $f'(c) = 0$  Regarding the step disontinuities... suppose $f(x) = \begin {cases} 0 &x<0\\x-x^2 & x \ge 0 \end {cases}$  and our interval is $[0,1]$  In this example $f(x)$ is continuous but not differentialbe at 0.

Comment: @Doug I have it the other way around, left-hand limit greater than or equal to $0$, and right-hand limit less than or equal to $0$. If $c$ is a maximum then the slopes on the left will be positive at best, and negative on the right at best. Or is this wrong?

Comment: @user525966: I think the easiest way to prove Rolle is to use mean value theorem

Comment: @Vasya I am trying to eventually use Rolle's Theorem to prove the MVT actually

Comment: @Vasya Frequently Rolle's theorem is used to prove the mean value theorem.

Comment: @user525966 If I have the signs flipped, it doesn't change the sentiment of my comment...

Comment: Do you have access to the extreme value theorem (a continuous function attains a maximum and a minimum on a closed set)?

Comment: @EricTowers I haven't proved that, no, I just sort of assumed it existed and went from there

Comment: @user525966: you can use that continuous function is bounded on a closed interval to prove that there is a maximum or you can use  extreme value theorem as Eric suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rearrange your start a little.

- By the extreme value theorem, there is a $c \in [a,b]$ which is a maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ and a $d \in [a,b]$ which is a minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$.  If these are both attained at the endpoints, then $f(a) = f(b) = f(c) = f(d)$, so $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$ and its derivative is zero everywhere on $[a,b]$.
- So suppose at least one of the maximum and the minimum are not attained at the endpoints.  (That is either the endpoints are strictly less than the maximum, the endpoints are strictly greater than the minimum, or both.)  We may suppose the maximum is attained in the interior, so $c \in (a,b)$.  (If it is only the minimum that is attained in the interior, we replace $f$ with $-f$ to convert to a maximum of $-f$ attained in the interior.)
  [Observe that the parabola $x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ attains its maximum on the endpoints and its minimum in the middle, and $-x^2$, vice versa, so this fiddling with minus signs isn't just formalism.]
- Observe that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, so both of the one-sided limits exist.  Do not include "$f'(c) = $".  By inspecting the signs, we get your two inequalities for these two one-sided limits.  Then recall that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, so these two limits must be equal to each other, hence to zero, and must be the derivative at $c$.  
  [This is pretty much what you did.  But you are building up to the derivative, so you should lay out the parts (the one-sided derivatives), then assemble them.  Otherwise you have more to explain -- "Why is this first one-sided limit the derivative?  Why is this second one-sided limit the derivative?  Wait, how can these two different expressions be the same thing?".  However, if you just say "this limit is non-negative, this limit is non-positive, and since $f$ is differentiable here, these limits are equal, zero, and $f'$", you have less you have to explain before you can explain what you need to explain.]

(As an alternative to the one-sided limits, use Fermat's theorem directly: $c$ is a point where $f$ has a local extremum, $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, containing $c$, so $f'$ is zero at $c$.  Notice if we go this way, we don't have to fiddle with minus signs, since whichever extremum is in the interior is the point with a zero derivative.)

Comment: How do you prove for example that $\lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} \geq 0$ technically? I don't even know if I can use epsilon delta for inequalities

Comment: This from the inequality $f(c+h) < f(c)$, so the ratio in the limit is negative over negative, hence positive.  The limit is then positive or zero, if it exists.  Hmm...  Okay, so we should mention that existence way earlier...  (Edited.)

Comment: I assume if it's differentiable then it allows us to say the limits exist. But is it enough to just talk about the signs of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: I've edited my answer to shuffle the mention of differentiability to before we use it to claim the two one-sided limits exist.  Assuming a limit exists, if all the values of the limit expression (I've called this "the limitand" by analogy with summand and integrand.) are in the set S, the limit is a point in the closure of S (i.e., is in S or is a boundary point of S).  In the left side case, all the values of the limitand are positive, giving positive or zero limit, and in the right side case, all the values of the limitand are negative, giving negative or zero limit.